MariaDB won't restart after oom-kill on Oracle Linux 9
I am in the process of migrating some of our servers to a new operating system after CentOS went out of support; and, as a replacement, we decided to move to Oracle Linux 9; specifically, MariaDB is version 10.6.18 and the OS is Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 9.4 (Plow).
However, I am now facing an issue where, if the databases service gets killed by the OOM-killer, it won't restart automatically, while it did on CentOS.
(By the way, I know that the OOM-killer shouldn't hit the database, that is another matter and not the focus of this question...).
Here is the logs of the last time this happened on one of these servers:
2024-08-08  2:40:05 0 [Note] /opt/agews64/bin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '10.6.18-MariaDB'  socket: '/opt/agews64/data/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
240808 03:18:13 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
240808 03:18:13 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
2024-08-08  3:18:13 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.6.18-MariaDB source revision 887bb3f73555ff8a50138a580ca8308b9b5c069c as process 157377
2024-08-08  3:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2024-08-08  3:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using transactional memory
2024-08-08  3:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2024-08-08  3:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2024-08-08  3:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2024-08-08  3:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 3221225472, chunk size = 134217728
2024-08-08  3:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2024-08-08  3:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=636943881408,636943881408
2024-08-08  3:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up in total 34 row operations to undo
2024-08-08  3:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: Trx id counter is 44113220
2024-08-08  3:18:13 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2024-08-08  3:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of recovered transactions
2024-08-08  3:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rolled back recovered transaction 44112559
2024-08-08  3:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
2024-08-08  3:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "/opt/agews64/data/mysql/ibtmp1"
2024-08-08  3:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2024-08-08  3:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '/opt/agews64/data/mysql/ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2024-08-08  3:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '/opt/agews64/data/mysql/ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2024-08-08  3:18:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.6.18 started; log sequence number 636943881876; transaction id 44113222
2024-08-08  3:18:14 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2024-08-08  3:18:14 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2024-08-08  3:18:14 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@vm-626suite-template' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2024-08-08  3:18:14 0 [Note] /opt/agews64/bin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '10.6.18-MariaDB'  socket: '/opt/agews64/data/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
2024-08-08  3:18:22 0 [Note] /opt/agews64/bin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2024-08-08  3:18:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2024-08-08  3:18:22 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2024-08-08  3:18:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "/opt/agews64/data/mysql/ibtmp1"
2024-08-08  3:18:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 636943890130; transaction id 44113962
2024-08-08  3:18:23 0 [Note] /opt/agews64/bin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete

As you can see on line 3, where it says 240808 03:18:13 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0, it seems that mysqld_safe correctly detected that fact that mariadbd had died, and dutifully restarted it.
However, starting from 2024-08-08  3:18:22 0 [Note] /opt/agews64/bin/mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown, that is, a few seconds after mysqld_safe restarted the database, immediately a new "clean" shutdown occurs.
After that, the database does not automatically restart.
For reference, here is the service definition for systemd:
[Unit]
Description=AGEws - Database
PartOf=agews.service
After=agews.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/opt/agews64/agews __start mysql
ExecStop=/opt/agews64/agews __stop mysql
ExecReload=/opt/agews64/agews __restart mysql
Restart=on-abort
KillMode=control-group
TimeoutSec=3600
OOMScoreAdjust=-750
MemoryAccounting=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=agews.service

The unit file uses Restart=on-abort as it seemed recommended in another question I found on the network.
After starting, the unit is dinamically modified based on available RAM; for this specific server, it sets MemoryHigh=5.5G and MemoryMax=6G.
What configuration change should I make so that MariaDB service automatically restart after being killed by OOM-killer?

I am keeping searching for info online, and I found https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadbd-safe/, which says that the mariadbd-safe script is is the recommended way to start mariadbd on Linux and Unix distributions that do not support systemd; since the ExecStart command actually calls that script, maybe instead it should just call mariadbd directly?

In the end, it seems that the problem was indeed caused by the fact that, despite having configured MariaDB as a Systemd service, I was still relying on mariadbd-safe to start the database server.
I am not really sure "why" it caused this problem, but I have changed the unit definition by adding Restart: on-failure and then calling mariadbd directly, avoiding the mariadbd-safe wrapper.
After this, the service was able to automatically restart when killed by the OOM-killer.
